# Pass a PHP variable from snippet to snippet in WordPress using the plugin 'Insert PHP Code Snippet'

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, plugins, code-snippets

How do I pass a PHP variable from snippet to snippet using the plugin "Insert PHP Code Snippet by XYZ"?

A snippet can be used by putting this `[xyz-ics snippet=”snippetname”]` in a textbox.

**Note: the snippets cannot be merged together because the variable will be named in the first snippet, and this variable will be used in the second snippet.**

Snippet 1:

```
<?php
   $test = 0;
?>
```

Snippet 2:

```
<?php
   echo $test;
?>
```

It somehow does not find the $test created in the first snippet.

I found *[How can I pass parameter using the snippet?](http://help.xyzscripts.com/docs/xyz-wp-insert-code-snippet-premium/faq/how-can-i-pass-parameter-using-the-snippet/)* with some information, but I am not sure if I can pass a PHP variable, because they only show hardcoded variables.

When in the same snippet, it does work:

```
<?php
  $test = 0;
  echo $test;
?>
```

Output:
`0`

Comment: php snippets in wordpress are usually treated as sandboxed objects, meaning that in most cases, they cannot parse variables outside of the snippet itself.
If in your case they happen to "escape" out of the snippet encasing, then possibly the second snippet is run before the first, resulting in $test being undefined

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it. If you are on the same server then you can use $GET and if you are using a different server then you should create cookies of value that use it in the other snippet.

Cookies will hold your value until you clear yourself by code or when the cookies time out. Please see the manual of [PHP cookies here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

Comment: And what if I do not want to use a global, session or cookie variable? Or is it a must?

Comment: if you do not use above that you mention, you can not hold the value, and in wordpress your can use add_option and get value any time where you want. you can learn about add_option here [add_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a global.

Snippet 1:

```
<?php
global $test;
$test=0;
?>
```

Snippet 2:

```
<?php
global $test;
echo $test;
?>
```